# How can I trigger auto focus and still keep current ISO and speed in camera2 API?

Tags: focus, android-camera2, manual

I did a try but when I touch to focus the preview is flashing. I dit it by trigger focus and reapply current ISO and speed at onCaptureCompleted. What wrong with it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reapplying ISO and exposure time? If you're staying with auto-exposure, it'll keep working automatically during and after the AF trigger.

So generally, just set CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER to START for a single capture request (not a repeating request!), keeping your other preview parameters the same.